# Intermitent errors even with the same seed - rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have huge specs in my rails application. Do you have any idea, why specs failure intermittently, even using the same seed.

For example, when I ran

```
rspec --seed 123 ./spec
```

all is ok. When I ran, again,

```
rspec --seed 123 ./spec
```

it could fail.

I like to put my code, but I have hundreds of specs.

Could you help me, please? Is there any technique to capture this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Given my experience, this could be an issue with feature specs not using Capybara's [waiting finders](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:MiA4Jqa-ytAJ:stefan.haflidason.com/testing-with-rails-and-capybara-methods-that-wait-method-that-wont/%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us). If a spec tests Javascript that adds an element to the DOM, then a Capybara finder that doesn't wait might not find the added element and testing for the existence of that element would fail. But it might find the element *sometimes* and so the spec would pass. Capybara finders that wait will keep trying to find the added element for a certain amount of time, which is usually enough time to find an element added to the DOM via Javascript.